# Error returning the results of an EXEC statement to a variable inside of SQL Server string

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic-sql

The following code does not work, and I am unsure why.

```
DECLARE @TableName varchar(100)
DECLARE @DBName varchar(50)
DECLARE @FinalTableName varchar(500)
DECLARE @TempDB  varchar(50)

SET @DBName=(select db_name())
SET @TableName = 'tbl_Product'
SET @FinalTableName = @DBName + '-' + @TableName +'-' + cast(CONVERT (date, GETDATE()) as varchar(100))
SET @TempDB = 'MiscDB.sys.objects'

Declare @SQL VarChar (250)
Declare @tableExist VarChar (200)

SET @SQL = 'select @tableExist =  OBJECT_ID FROM ' + @TempDB + ' WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(''' + @TableName + ''') AND type in (N''U'')'
exec @SQL
```

I get this error

> Msg 911, Level 16, State 4, Line 15
>   Database 'select @tableExist =  OBJECT_ID FROM MiscDB' does not exist. Make sure that the name is entered correctly.

If I run the SQL statement directly, however, it does work.

Comment: Did you try `EXEC sp_executesql @SQL;`? Also if you know the name of the table, why are you comparing `object_id`, when sys.objects has the name?

Comment: why do you have the `@tableExist` inside of the sql string?  if it is there I don't believe it will be defined when you try to execute it.

Comment: Add `Print @Sql` in a line before the exec one. What does it print?

Comment: Dani, if i Print the @Sql and run it, it works.

Comment: bluefeet, how else should it be done? I want to check if table exists in another db.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query should probably be:

```
DECLARE 
  @dbname      SYSNAME,
  @tablename   SYSNAME,
  @tableExists INT,
  @sql         NVARCHAR(MAX);

SELECT 
  @dbname    = N'Misc',
  @tablename = N'tbl_product';

SET @sql = N'SELECT @tableExists = [object_id]
    FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@dbname) + '.sys.tables 
    WHERE name = @tablename;';

EXEC sp_executesql @sql,
    N'@tableExists BIT OUTPUT, @tablename SYSNAME',
    @tableExists OUTPUT, @tablename;

PRINT @tableExists;
```

If the database name is fixed (you seem to have hard-coded `Misc`) it is slightly easier:

```
DECLARE 
  @tablename   SYSNAME,
  @tableExists INT,
  @sql         NVARCHAR(MAX);

SELECT 
  @tablename = N'tbl_product';

SET @sql = N'SELECT @tableExists = OBJECT_ID(@tablename, N''U'');';

EXEC Misc..sp_executesql @sql,
    N'@tableExists BIT OUTPUT, @tablename SYSNAME',
    @tableExists OUTPUT, @tablename;

PRINT @tableExists;
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple problems-

The first is that anything written in dynamic SQL is in a different scope- inside of your dynamic SQL you cannot set a variable that was declared outside of the dynamic SQL.

The second is that OBJECT_ID() is by database- you're executing this on a database that likely does not have a table named tbl_Product.

Try the following:

```
SET @SQL = 'USE ' + @TempDB + ' select OBJECT_ID FROM ' + @TempDB + ' WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(''' + @TableName + ''') AND type in (N''U'')'
exec @SQL
```

This is just basically "Use @TempDB from now on" from the top, so you don't have to deal with some of these scope issues (ObjectId attempting to be found from your current connection's DB) and we also dropped out the setting of the variable inside the scope as that is not going to work.